# Structure of "Ich war laufen"

Tags: difference, grammar-identification

I've heard the phrase or the question "Ich war laufen" or "Warst du laufen? I assume it's another way to say "Ich bin laufen gegangen", is that right?

- What is the difference between both constructions and in which cases is the one used instead of the other?
- Does this apply to all verbs which require "sein" form instead of "haben" in the perfect tense?

Comment: This construction is called *Absentiv*, and there is even a Wikipedia article about it: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absentiv

Answer (score 1):

The construct "ich war laufen" / "Ich bin laufen gegangen" is, as RHa pointed out correctly, called *Absentiv*.

Both your examples are not so much an answer to "what did you do?" but rather to "where have you been?"

You were asked for a *location* and answer with an *activity* (which may somehow imply a location - If you answer "ich war schwimmen" that closely implies you might have been somewhere where this is possible, probably to the pool). That *activity* is your reasoning why you have been *absent*, thus *Absentiv*.

The difference between your two examples is mainly that

> Ich war laufen

would answer the question "where have you been?" and

> Ich bin laufen gegangen

would answer the question "where did you go?"

The *Absentiv* is *always* constructed with some form of "sein" + infinitive, regardless of whether the verb would rather take "haben" as auxiliary in perfect tense:

> Ich war arbeiten

Means "I was at work/in the office/workshop/...", even if *arbeiten* requires "haben" as auxiliary in perfect tense.

Answer (score 0):

No, *laufen sein* and *laufen gehen* are two different things. The difference is about Northern and Southern German:

> Wo warst du? — Ich war laufen. *(Northern German and writing use **Präteritum**)*
>
> Wo bist du gewesen? — Ich bin laufen gewesen. *(Southern German uses **Perfekt**)*

Instead of a place where someone was, she responds with an action, *laufen*. This is pretty logical because when you constantly move, you haven't been at a single place of interest.

This use of the bare infinitive follows the pattern of modal verbs:

> Ich wollte laufen. *(Northern German and writing use **Präteritum**)*
>
> Ich habe laufen gewollt. *(Southern German uses **Perfekt**)*

---

For the main verb *gehen*, Northern and Southern German both use **Perfekt**.

> Ich ging laufen. *(Writing uses **Präteritum**)*
>
> Ich bin laufen gegangen. *(Speech uses **Perfekt**)*

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. It was helpful.
just one thing I want to mention, I live in Bavaria, which is supposed to be Southern German and here I hear people use Präteritum as you pointed out in the first example. I guess that Bavarian is a bit different than the German as they like to say :)

Comment: *Zugereiste.* No, actually, there's some many people from the north in Bavaria their way of speech spread widely.

Comment: Ich bin laufen gewesen is generally right in German, not only South. And I reckon Ich war laufen is also right in the South

Comment: The more north you get, the more people use Präteritum forms in speech. But I think you are right, *sein* is one of the few verbs even Bavarians use Präteritum in speech.

Comment: ... with the caveat that in the Southern parts of Germany nobody would say *Ich habe laufen gewollt* using this standard variety of German. People will use their dialects, e.g. Swabian *I han laufa wella*, *I bee laufa ganga*, *I bee laufa gwäa*. As soon as they switch over to standard pronuncation, they (tend to) use also more "northern" (as Janka puts it) syntax, e.g. *Ich wollt' laufen*, *Ich war laufen*, etc.

Comment: In the north, people don't actually use in speech *Ich war laufen*, but *'wa laufn*, *'wollt laufn*. But it makes not much sense to introduce dialects into writing when discussing the different grammar of northern and southern German.

Comment: Oh, and Swabian uses the *Ersatzinfinitiv* in this case?

Comment: I’m pretty sure this answer entirely misses the point. By a marathon.

Comment: @Janka Bist du dir über „Ich habe laufen gewollt. (Southern German uses Perfekt)“ sicher? Ich bin zwar aus Hamburg, habe aber Familie in Schwaben, und „Ich habe laufen wollen.“ („I han laufe wella.“) klingt für mich viel natürlicher.

Comment: edit: Habe gerade den Kommentar von @ChristianGeiselmann gesehen, damit erübrigt sich mein Kommentar eigentlich.

Comment: Schwäbisch/Alemannisch benutzen auch den Ersatzinfinitiv. Fränkisch vielleicht nicht, aber da verstehe ich sowieso nichts.